# Getting stack trace from ember route error

Tags: ember.js, ember-router, ember-cli

I went though [this presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/elucid/ember-errors-and-you) and added the necessary `Ember.onerror(error);` to the application route's error action. However, when I attempt to log the error, I am getting what seems to be the route object (not sure what it is). Are there some additional steps I need to take? I'm using Ember CLI v.40 and Ember v1.6.1.

```
// routes/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        ...

        error: function(error) {
            Ember.onerror(error);
            return true;
        }
    }
});


// initializers/bugsnag.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default {
    name  : 'bugsnag',
    after : 'ajax-prefilter',

    initialize: function(container) {
        var appController, currentRoute;

        try {
            appController = container.lookup('controller:application');
            currentRoute  = appController.get('currentPath');
        } catch(e) {}

        var context = { currentRoute: currentRoute };

        Ember.onerror = function(error) {
            // do something with error
            console.log(error.stack) // undefined on route error
        };
    }
};
```

I get the following in the console (produced by ember, not my code), which is the information I'm attempting to get in the initializer:

```
Error while processing route: calendar.create
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been using console.trace() in my route error handling method.

```
Em.Logger.log(error.stack);
if(! Em.isNone(console)) {
  console.trace();
}
```

This usually produces enough info to further debug the issue.  Note that using Em.Logger instead of console.log it will handle the case where some browser don't have console defined.